# Best way to organize fast read of entire table for 10 and more connections in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with about 200k-400k records in it, 6 columns. Size of it when dumped to python's json array not exceeds 16MB.
There are 20 connections, that at certain period of time are going to read ENTIRE table.
How can I optimize this process? Is there is a way to 'prepare' this data (maybe cache it in the RAM directly)?
Can you propose best solution for such tables?

Comment: Postgres will already cache the data. Additionally if two connections are doing the same query, the second one will join the I/O work done by the first ("Synchronized Seq Scans")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what if they are doing different queries?

Comment: You wrote all of them are reading the entire table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am just trying to know how can I boost the performance for this table since it is really small (as I told just a couple of megabytes) for multiple connections. Yeah, initially there will be just entire table retrieve, but I will want to filter by some condition in future. And I want to optimize it ofc. Since the table size is small I was thinking is this possible to put it into the RAM entirely. Or just pre-compile a couple of queries, or something like that...

Comment: As I said: Postgres **will** cache the data in RAM once it is retrieved

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks. One more question - does it do it by default, or I need to set up some setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL will cache the table in RAM the first time it is read.

An exception to this is if the table is bigger than a quarter of `shared_buffers`: then PostgreSQL will use a small ring buffer for the sequential scan to avoid blowing out the whole cache. But that seems unlikely with a small table like that.

If you want to speed up the first scan of the table too, you can load it into RAM explicitly:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_prewarm;

SELECT pg_prewarm('table_name');
```